# Sqoop Merge failed when selected time stamp as column in incremental update

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I want to practise sqoop merge command .
What I have done is I have imported data to HDFS from MySQL DB and then updated the source table with 1 update and 1 insert , my table has `id` as primary key and `time` as TIMESTAMP .

Next I did once again the import with `--incremental=lastmodified --check-column="time"` option.

Then did sqoop merge , but it failed with below error. I think there is some mismatch between the data sets of earlier import and latest import but not able to understand what is wrong. Is that because of importing with `--check-column=time` ? If I update with `--where` clause it works.

I used :-

```
--Initial load
sqoop import \
  --connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/testdb" \
  --username=root \
  --password=cloudera \
  --table Customers \
  --as-textfile \
  --target-dir=/user/cloudera/sqoop_import/sqoop_merge/Customers

sqoop import \
  --connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/testdb" \
  --username=root \
  --password=cloudera \
  --table Customers \
  --as-textfile \
  --target-dir=/user/cloudera/sqoop_import/sqoop_merge/Customers_delta \
  --incremental lastmodified \
  --check-column "time" \
  --last-value '2016-08-24 22:04:56.0'

sqoop merge --merge-key department_id \
  --new-data /user/cloudera/sqoop_import/sqoop_merge/Customers_delta \
  --onto /user/cloudera/sqoop_import/sqoop_merge/Customers \
  --target-dir /user/cloudera/sqoop_import/sqoop_merge/Customers_merge \
  --class-name Customers \
  --jar-file /tmp/sqoop-cloudera/compile/d73387fb05f4fcb0d38725806fe52b30/Customers.jar
```

And error is :-

> 16/08/24 22:49:41 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 13% reduce 0%
>       16/08/24 22:49:42 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1471947772048_0032_m_000003_2, Status : FAILED
>       Error: java.io.IOException: Cannot join values on null key. Did you specify a key column that exists?
>           at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.MergeMapperBase.processRecord(MergeMapperBase.java:79)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.MergeTextMapper.map(MergeTextMapper.java:58)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.MergeTextMapper.map(MergeTextMapper.java:34)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:340)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1554)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)

Any clue to find out the cause will be really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Is `department_id` your primary key?

Comment: Thanks dev ,,, I figured out the primary key is the problem here . I have changed to "id" as thats the primary key for table . it really worked.

Answer (score 0):

You table has `id` primary key field.

Use `--merge-key id` in your command.

As per your error logs,

> Cannot join values on null key. Did you specify a key column that exists?

It seems `department_id` is not a field in your table.

Comment: Yes Dev , u are right , resolved . status closed , thanks